# .module missing from intellisense with TypeScript and angular.d.ts

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I'm running Visual Studio 2013 update 4 with Web Essentials.  I've used NuGet to install the `angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped` package.

I've created an app directory and created a `app.module.ts` file in the app directory.  I then add the following:

```
(():void => {
    'use strict' ;

    angular.module('app',[]);
})();
```

First, when I type the . after angular, only get the following intelli-sense items:

- animate
- cookies
- IModule
- resource
- route
- sanitize

Second, module is left with a red squiggly with a message that reads:
`property 'module' does not exist on value of type 'typeof angular'.`

What am I missing here?

Comment: do you have `/// <reference path="angular.d.ts" />` in your file?

Comment: yes, it acts the same way with or without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently is was my version of TypeScript (1.0.3).  Even though I had VS 2013 Update 4 and Web Essentials, I was still working with an old version.  I downloaded and installed the latest TypeScript version (1.5) and that fixed the issue.